# find the string present and update the frequency

Tags: r

I have 2 dataframes, I am trying to find if the words from `df` dataframe is present in dataframe sentence's texts then I need to mutate source values as columns and print frequency for each source value. Please help me to achieve this!

```
df <- data.frame(words = c("this","when","from","car","good"), source = c("name1", "name1","name2", "name2","name3"))

sentence <- data.frame(Textno = c(1,2,3),texts = c("when this job comes", "the car is good", "from here"))
```

Expected Output

```
Textno  texts                name1 name2 name3
  1     when this job comes    2     0     0
  2     the car is good        0     1     0
  3     from here              0     0     1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing is basically looking up words from a dictionary - which is often done when doing sentiment analysis ([see](https://www.tidytextmining.com/sentiment.html)). You can use `tidytext` and some commands from `dplyr` and `tidyr` to accomplish this:

```
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
sentence %>% 
  unnest_tokens(output = "words", input = "texts", drop = FALSE) %>% # split up words into a tidy format
  left_join(df, by = "words") %>% # join sentences and the dictionary
  filter(!is.na(source)) %>% # remove cases where there was no match
  count(Textno, texts, source) %>%  # count the matches
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(Textno, texts), names_from = source, 
              values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0)) # tidy up your output
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   Textno texts               name1 name2 name3
#>    <dbl> <chr>               <int> <int> <int>
#> 1      1 when this job comes     2     0     0
#> 2      2 the car is good         0     1     1
#> 3      3 from here               0     1     0
```

*I set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` while creating the two example `data.frames`.

It's also possible (and likely faster on larger objects) in `quanteda`:

```
library(quanteda)
dict <- df %>% 
  group_by(source) %>%
  summarise(words = list(words)) %>% 
  select(word = words, sentiment = source) %>% # quanteda expects a very particular format when creating a dictionary
  as.dictionary()

corpus(sentence, docid_field = "Textno", text_field = "texts") %>% 
  dfm(dictionary = dict) %>% # this creates a document feature matrix but only with words from the dictionary
  convert("data.frame")
#>   document name1 name2 name3
#> 1        1     2     0     0
#> 2        2     0     1     1
#> 3        3     0     1     0
```

Or you can try `stringr` for a more manual approach:

```
res <- lapply(unique(df$source), function(src) { # loop over every source
  stringr::str_count(sentence$texts, pattern = paste0(df$words[df$source == src], collapse = "|")) # count number of times a word from the source appears
})
names(res) <- unique(df$source) # name the resulting list, which fives you nice column names later

cbind(sentence, res) # binding the list to your data.frame
#>   Textno               texts name1 name2 name3
#> 1      1 when this job comes     2     0     0
#> 2      2     the car is good     0     1     1
#> 3      3           from here     0     1     0
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do this by first seperating into words.
Consequently melt the dataframe to long format and join with `df`.
Lastly you cast the data.frame back to the wide format.

```
sentence %>% 
  tidyr::separate(texts, into = paste0("word", 1:10), sep = " ", remove = FALSE) %>% 
  reshape2::melt(id.vars = c("Textno", "texts")) %>% 
  left_join(df, by = c("value" = "words")) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  reshape2::dcast(Textno  + texts ~ source)


Textno               texts name1 name2 name3
1      when this job comes     2     0     0
2          the car is good     0     1     1
3                from here     0     1     0
```

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, could u pls explain me ``` paste0("word", 1:10)``` what does it means by 1:10?

Comment: This might not be the cleanest of approaches, but I split the sentences into words (separates by a space: `sep = “”`). Separate takes an `into` parameter. I create 10 new coloms, named word1 ... to word10.